# Can I nest a <figcaption> element within <a> tags from default wordpress?

Tags: gallery, links, block-editor, captions

I am making a page with Gutenberg but there is a problem that the link does not work within a . This is the code when I inspect:

```
<figure>
  <a href="...">
  <img>
  </a>
  <figcaption>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is there some way that I could nested the figcaption within the a tags so it could be clickable ? I can not modify the code because it is generated by Wordpress.

The expected output:

```
<figure>
  <a href="...">
  <img>
  <figcaption>
  </figcaption>
  </a>

</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is manipulating the DOM in Javascript: Select all `figure` containing an `a`, look for its `figcaption` and append it to the `a`.